# How to block Websocket protocol (to simulate corporate firewalls) on Ubuntu?

Tags: websocket, firewall, fallback

I am working on a web app that uses WebSockets, and I know that many corporate firewalls block it.  Now I have added Socket.io to fallback to XHR polling in case Websockets are blocked.

But I can't figure out how to simulate this environment for testing. How can I simulate an environment similar to corporate firewalls?

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, but can switch to Windows 7 if required. Am open to any different approaches as well.

Comment: So I would simply run the app on an emulator and block the actual ports on my PC to simulate that environment on Ubuntu - sudo ufw enable - sudo ufw reject out {PORT}

Answer (score 2):

install squid and tell your browser to use it as a proxy.

Comment: squid sqid doesn't proxy websocket. so websocket will be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get socket.io to error on websocket connect using Fiddler. In Filters, I set Delete response headers to delete the header `Connection: Upgrade`.